# How to manipulate array reference in subroutine in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, reference

Im passing array by reference to a subroutine:

```
my @template_ops;
handle_templates_with_post_mod(\@template_ops);

sub handle_templates_with_post_mod
{
    my @my_template_ops    = @{$_[0]};
    unshift (@my_template_ops), 'O';
}
```

but after calling the subroutine the array still empty, I have tried:

```
sub handle_templates_with_post_mod
{
    my $my_template_ops    = shift;
    unshift (@$my_template_ops), 'O';
}
```

but I get this error: `Can't use string ("...") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Four issues:

1. ALWAYS turn on `use strict; use warnings;`
2. Then `unshift (@$my_template_ops), 'O';` would have produced `Useless use of unshift with no values at ./t.pl line 17.`.
   You have set the parens `()` wrong. Either write `unshift (@$my_template_ops, 'O');` or just leave them off completely: `unshift @$my_template_ops, 'O';`
3. The code `my @my_template_ops = @{$_[0]};` generates a *copy* of the supplied array reference and you are manipulating the *copy*. Thus you don't see the effect at top level.
4. The 2nd version of your function works because you operate on the supplied array ref and just dereference it for the `unshift` call.

Working version:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @template_ops;
handle_templates_with_post_mod(\@template_ops);

print Data::Dumper::Dumper( \@template_ops );

sub handle_templates_with_post_mod
{
    my $my_template_ops    = shift;
    unshift @$my_template_ops, 'O';
}
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'O'
        ];
```

Answer (score 2):

When you give the dereferenced array a name, it becomes a copy. To operate on an array ref and affect the original array, you either need to use it as a ref, or dereference it without giving it a new name (using the `@` operator to dereference).

```
my $arrayRef = ...;
push @{$arrayRef}, 42;
my $hashRef = ...;
delete $hashRef->{key};
```

Comment: @PerlDuck Thanks. I changed it to a hash ref, since deleting hash elements is safe and still illustrates the syntax.